# Any chance to recover unicode data from varchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Unicode data (cyrillic) was written into database column of type `varchar`

Is there any chance to recover that data in correct format?

It doesn't have to be fully recovered, anything will be great

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5):

No.

This is a lossy conversion as double byte characters cannot possibly all be represented in a single byte scheme. All characters not coercible into the code page of your default collation will have been converted to `?`.

There is no way of reverse engineering back what that `?` originally was supposed to represent or any other less severe conversions that may have happened along the way (e.g characters converted to somewhat similar homopglyph characters).

Example

```
DECLARE @T TABLE 
(
V VARCHAR(10)
)
INSERT INTO @T 
VALUES (N'中华人民共和国');

SELECT V,
       CAST(V AS VARBINARY(10))
FROM @T
```

Output

```
V          
---------- ----------------------
???????    0x3F3F3F3F3F3F3F
```

You can clearly see that all the different characters in the source get stored as the same thing.